# How do I send logs received at one graylog to another graylog?

Tags: graylog

I have two graylog servers, one on an older version of graylog (server 1) that is receiving logs (version 1).

I have another graylog server (version 2), let's call it server 2 that I would like to send all the logs received at server 1 to. I would like to have a way to send all the logs received by server 1 to server 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "Catchall" stream which will include all ingested messages (e. g. check for the presence of the `timestamp` message field) and then assign a [GELF output](http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.3/pages/streams.html#outputs) to that stream.

This would, additionally to indexing everything in ES, send all messages to your second Graylog cluster.